# How would I ADD AN ADDITIONAL structure to the end of a structure array? in C

Tags: c, arrays, append

Or more general question: how would I append an additional element to the end of an array in C?

```
int i;

int arr[5] = {1,2,3,4,5};
int len = 5;

for( i = len-1; i >= 0; i++)
{
    scanf("%d",&arr[i+1]);
    printf("%d",arr[i+1]);
}
```

Comment: By (re)allocating a new array that's large enough to hold all of your elements.

Comment: you should be more specific with your question. write an example, and write a question that is specific to that example.  I think if you do this, you will probably answer your own question anyway

Comment: but what if the array size is dynamic?

Comment: @Petiatil: By using `realloc()`.

Answer (score 2):

You can't. Array sizes are set when you create the array, and can't be changed later. If you decide you need more space, you have to create a new, larger array.

If you want something that can be resized, you'll have to use something other than an array. Maybe create a linked list.

Answer (score 2):

If the size of the array will be known only during runtime, you will have to declare a pointer and dynamically allocate memory.

But if your requirement is something which can grow in capacity, you will have to go for some dynamic data structure, like a linked list. It will allow you to add new nodes (it can contain whatever data you want it to hold).